# 'child_of' in get_posts not working

Tags: get-posts, php

I don't know why, but for some reason neither `parent` or `child_of` are being accepted as arguments in `get_posts` that I'm using a `foreach` loop.

```
$sidebarReviews = get_posts(array(
    'child_of'       => get_ID_by_slug('testimonial-reviews'),
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
    'post_type'      => 'page' 
));
```

Note: the `get_ID_by_slug` is a custom function I have just to translate slugs into page IDs. This is working correctly.

However, when my foreach runs, it seems to pick up every page that's in my Wordpress database.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confused arguments with those for *term* functions. :)

For posts the correct argument is `post_parent`.

Comment: Hmm you're right, that must have slipped past me. I think I got confused between the note on the Codex saying, you can use the arguments in get_pages, of which I believe it's listed in there.

Comment: Right, `get_pages()` has those too... WordPress is consistent like that, ugh. :)